# I have general questions about Diffie-Hellman parameters

Tags: security, aes, diffie-hellman

I am currently working on Diffie-Hellman Key exchange and use the key pairs for AES.

Q1) When I choose prime for Diffie-Hellman from RFC 3526 such as 1536, 2048, 3072 MODP groups, is bigger prime safer? could you explain me about it?

Q2) Each group all has generator of 2, should I always use 2 as generator if I use standard prime group from RFC3526??

Q3) I am using the key pairs from Diffie-Hellman for AES. I understand that AES's key length can be 128, 192 or 256 bits. Should I choose specific prime or generator in Diffie-Hellman to meet the key lengths of 128, 192 or 256 bit for AES??

Sorry ask three questions in a single post but I believe that they are all related questions. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In [RFC 3528](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3526.txt), they address your questions in section 8, Security Considerations. I will attempt to restate/explain the answers here:

1. In short, yes, the bigger prime is "safer". Assuming that Diffie-Hellman is not fundamentally broken, the difficulty of "cracking" the exchange, i.e. finding out the shared key the exchange establishes, scales directly with the size of the primes used. However, one additional bit of prime does not equal one additional bit of "key strength" in AES terms. This is because, simply, not every number is prime. In AES-128, for example, we expect the key to be a string of 128 random bits, meaning that the key could be any one of 2^128 possibilities. Yet we would never use a 128-bit prime in Diffie-Hellman (or RSA, or anything else that requires primes) simply because there are much fewer than 2^128 primes that are 128 bits in length. So if we used a 128-bit prime, an attacker wouldn't have to try all of the 2^128 possibilities, they would only have to try the much smaller number of 128-bit primes. Therefore, in order to say we have the same "key-strength" as AES-x, we need to use much, much larger primes, so that we have a number of possible primes in the range of 2^x.
2. I would say yes. When in doubt, follow the reference implementation; in this case, use 2 as the generator.
3. The table in section 8 shows the "strength estimate" of the various prime groups provided; I would always take the lower estimate of their strength. So for AES-128, use at least the 3072-bit group; for AES-192, at least the 8192-bit group.

Comment: Thanks It really helped me ha!

Comment: The general advice is correct, though the reasoning behind it is not so correct.  Breaking DH has nothing to do with the number of primes up to some size (we know that number, btw, it is given by the prime number theorem).  Instead, its security depends upon the difficulty of cracking a prime using the [number field sieve](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~psh/ANTproc/12oliver.pdf).  The running time of this algorithm is order e^[(1 + o(1))^(1.923 (Log p)^(1/3) * (Log Log p)^(2/3))].  Logarithms are natural.  Setting p on the order of 2^3072 gives running time around 2^128.

Comment: @TheGreatContini Can I ask one more question? what does the strength estimate exactly mean? like for 3072-bit group the strength estimate ranges from 130 ~ 210 bits. Does it mean that 3072-bit group is recommended for encryption using key in that range??

Comment: @F. Stephen Q   Can I ask one more question? what does the strength estimate exactly mean? like for 3072-bit group the strength estimate ranges from 130 ~ 210 bits. Does it mean that 3072-bit group is recommended for encryption using key in that range?

Comment: @Michael yes, that is correct.  It is essentially the log of number of operations to break it.  So if the document says strength estimate is 130, then the number of operations to break that DH group is on the order of 2^130.  The concept is that the DH strength estimate should not be less than the effort to break the key you are exchanging.  A 128-bit AES key takes effort 2^128 to crack, so in this case you are doing things right by using 3072-DH to exchange 128-bit AES, but you shouldn't use it to exchange 256-but AES.